# Doubt on asymptotics of continous functions (little-o notation and taylor expansion).

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, self-learning

Suppose I have $e^{(\frac{1}{n}b + o(\frac{1}{n}))}$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} = e^0 = 1$ so $$e^{(\frac{1}{n}b + o(\frac{1}{n}))} =  o(1) +1$$

But if I take the Taylor expansion of $e^{(\frac{1}{n}b + o(\frac{1}{n}))}$ I get that $$e^x = 1+\frac{1}{n}b + o(\frac{1}{n}) $$

Are these both correct(due to the misuse of notation one does not negate the other) ? In the cases when one can use the Taylor expansion does it always give better information?

Comment: In your second line that should be $1+o(1)$ on the right.

Comment: Yep I will edit